# unable to build dcm4chee-arc-cdi

Tags: maven, dcm4che

I'm trying to build dcm4chee-arc-cdi with code cloned from github: https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-arc-cdi

However when issuing the build command as described at the README.md

`mvn install -D db=psql` I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dcm4chee-arc-conf: Could
>   not resolve dependencies for project
>   org.dcm4che.dcm4chee-arc:dcm4chee-arc-conf:jar:4.5.0-SNAPSHOT: The
>   following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   org.dcm4che:dcm4che-conf-api:jar:3.3.8-SNAPSHOT,
>   org.dcm4che:dcm4che-conf-dicom:jar:3.3.8-SNAPSHOT,
>   org.dcm4che:dcm4che-imageio:jar:3.3.8-SNAPSHOT,
>   org.dcm4che:dcm4che-net-hl7:jar:3.3.8-SNAPSHOT,
>   org.dcm4che:dcm4che-conf-api-hl7:jar:3.3.8-SNAPSHOT,
>   org.dcm4che:dcm4che-soundex:jar:3.3.8-SNAPSHOT,
>   org.dcm4che.dcm4chee-storage:dcm4chee-storage-service:jar:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   Failure to find org.dcm4che:dcm4che-conf-api:jar:3.3.8-SNAPSHOT in
>   http://www.dcm4che.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to overcome this?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that some other projects needed to be built before dcm4chee-arc-cdi.

Those were:

```
The dcm4che 3 library ( https://github.com:dcm4che/dcm4che )
The configuration layer ( https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-conf )
The storage layer ( https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-storage2 )
The monitoring framework ( https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-monitoring )
```

Comment: Exactly I just confirm that are the projects you have to install first and in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the release repository (http://www.dcm4che.org/maven2/) is not holding the expected versions.

Take `dcm4che-conf-api-hl7` for example. Its declared version (3.3.8-SNAPSHOT) does not exist in  http://www.dcm4che.org/maven2/org/dcm4che/dcm4che-conf-api-hl7/
I guess the others are similar errors.

I suggest you contact one of the project's contributors like [Umberto Cappellini](https://github.com/umberto-cappellini)

For a temp solution, you can edit the main `pom.xml` and replace the missing versions with actual versions you find in the repository I mentioned above.

I hope this helps.

Comment: A public maven repository may choose to expose only non-snapshot versions of software packages. It is quite common to have a separate repository (i.e. accessible through a somewhat different URL) that contains snapshot versions of software packages.


There is nothing inherently wrong with mixing snapshot and non-snapshot versions in the same repository, but that is not usually the way things are done in maven.